# Intersection types with Covariance

Tags: scala, generics, dotty, scala-3

Consider the below:

```
trait AA {
    def children: List[AA]
}

trait BB {
    def children: List[BB]
}

class CC extends AA, BB {
    override def children: List[AA] & List[BB] = ???
}
```

When we override `children` in `CC`, the overridden method is merged entity of the top-level methods. And hence the return type `List[AA] & List[BB]` makes sense.

What I don't understand is, how does the below compile?

```
class DD extends AA, BB {
    override def children: List[AA & BB] = ???
}
```

List is co-variant, hence (here is the source for [proof](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/intersection-types-spec.html#subtyping-rules)):

```
List[AA & BB] <: List[AA] & List[BB]
```

`DD` can only compile if *also* `List[AA] & List[BB] <: List[AA & BB]`. Is it true?
And if so, then isn't `List[AA] & List[BB] =:= List[AA & BB]`. Please suggest

---

It appears to me that `List[AA & BB] =:= List[AA] & List[BB]`. Consider this:

```
    val xx: List[AA & BB] = ???
    val yy: List[AA] & List[BB] = ???
    
    val z1: List[AA] & List[BB] = xx
    val z2: List[AA & BB] = yy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write that for DD to compile, `List[AA] & List[BB]` must be a subtype of `List[AA & BB]`. I don't see why you think that, and you're in fact mistaken. Method return types are covariant, and hence it's the other way around: `List[AA & BB]` must be a subtype of `List[AA] & List[BB]`. And this is indeed the case, so the code is fine.

Comment: function return type being covariance answers it.

Answer (score 4):

Matthias Berndt already answered that `List[AA] & List[BB] <: List[AA & BB]` is not needed for your code to compile. However, a separate point is that it is in fact true (and so is `List[AA] & List[BB] =:= List[AA & BB]`). Why?

1. Consider a value `x` of type `List[AA] & List[BB]`.
2. It must be both a `List[AA]` and `List[BB]`.
3. That is, both a list of `AA`s and a list of `BB`s.
4. So any element `y` of this list must be an `AA` because `x` is a list of `AA`s, and a `BB` because `x` is a list of `BB`s.
5. So `y` must be an `AA & BB`.
6. Since every element of `x` has type `AA & BB`, `x` has type `List[AA & BB]`.

This reasoning is specific to `List`, but it generalizes [and not just to covariant types](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/intersection-types-spec.html):

> If `C` is a type constructor, then `C[A] & C[B]` can be simplified using the following three rules:
>
> - If `C` is covariant, `C[A] & C[B] ~> C[A & B]`
> - If `C` is contravariant, `C[A] & C[B] ~> C[A | B]`
> - If `C` is non-variant, emit a compile error